# How to extract only values from array of objects and put it to an array using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an array of objects like below

```
const SelectedOptions = [
    {
        label: 'label1',
        value: '1',
    },
    {
        label: 'label2',
        value: '2',
    }
];
```

I use this selectedOption array in the onChange method of select menu like below

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <Select
            options={options}
            onChange((selectedOptions) => {
                form.setFieldValue('optionsChosen', selectedOptions);
            });
        />
    );
}
```

Now the problem with above onChange method is that, i want to set field OptionsChosen to an array of values only.

so in the onchange method i want to map through selectedOptions and extract only values field and put it to optionsChosen field.

so the expected array to optionsChosen field is like below,

```
["1", "2"];
```

how can i do it. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert an *array of objects* into an *array of values*

```js
const SelectedOptions = [
{
    label: 'label1',
    value: '1',
},
{
    label: 'label2',
    value: '2',
}
];

result = SelectedOptions.map(option => option.value);

console.log(result);
```